# php glob get right path

Tags: php, path, glob

I need to load images from specific folder to array.

I use glob function and have some problems with path.

I call php script via $.getJSON from jquery and pass the url of first image in folder.

```
$filename = $_GET['fname'];
$thumbsPath = dirname($filename);    
$images = glob($thumbsPath.'*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE);
```

- $filename is localhost/myproject/images/10.jpg
- $thumbsPath is localhost/myproject/images/
- the php scritp folder is localhost/myproject/scripts/

Filestructure is:

```
localhost
-scripts/
--script.js
--globscript.php
-images/
--10.jpg
--11.jpg
--12.jpg
--...
-index.html
```

and glob function returns results only if i use **../images/** as path.

How can I solve it? Thx!

And the other problem, that i need either urls or pathes relative to index.html in resulting array...

Comment: So, if `$thumbsPath = '../images/';` it works?

Comment: yes it works in such a way, but the path must be generated automatic based on image url...

Comment: All of your images are stored in `/images` correct?

Comment: at the time - yes, but the folder name or filestracture can vary

Comment: the folder is defined by user and can be anywhere on server, i think, the Method from Fred is much better, than glob...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe this will do what you want :

```
$dir = dirname($filename);
$dh = opendir($dir);
while ($img = readdir($dh)) {
    // type validation with filetype($dir.$img);
}
closedir($dh);
```

that way, it should never matter where is the image folder

Comment: It looks like this only support subdirectory up to 1 level. Say if I have multiple levels of subdirectories, for example /img/works/ it would only point the cursor to img.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$filename = $_GET['fname'];
$thumbsPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . 'myproject/images/' . $filename;    
$images = glob($thumbsPath.'*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE);
```

Comment: no, it does not work neither with C:/xampp/htdocs/localhost/myproject/images/

Comment: I made an edit to the `$thumbPath` variable. Try that. Basically, you'll need to define the path to your images. `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` will take you to the root then build the path from there.